# Creating custom routes where a model attribute is used instead of the ID in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, custom-routes

I have a model called `Student`, which has an attribute called `University_ID` in it.

I created a custom action and route which displays the details of a specific student via the following link :`students/2/details`i.e. `students/:id/details`

However, I want to be able to allow the user to use their university ID instead of the database ID so that the following would work for instance `students/X1234521/details`
 i.e. `students/:university_id/details`

My route file looks like this at the moment:

```
resources :students
match 'students/:id/details' => 'students#details', :as => 'details'
```

However this uses the Student_ID as opposed to the University_ID, and I've tried doing

`match 'students/:university_id/details' => 'students#details', :as => 'details'`, but that only corresponds to the Student_ID, not the University_ID.

My controller looks like this, if this helps in any way:

```
def details
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
end
```

I also tried doing `@student = Student.find(params[:university_id])` but nope, nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chatting with @teenOmar to clarify the requirements, here's the solution we came up with, which allows for the existing `students/:id/details` route to accept either an `id` or a `university_id` (which starts with a `w`), and uses a `before_filter` to populate `@student` for use in various controller actions:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :find_student, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :details]

  def show
    # @student will already be loaded here
    # do whatever
  end

  # same for edit, update, details

private

  def find_student
    if params[:id] =~ /^w/
      @student = Student.find_by_university_id(params[:id])
    else
      @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Or try `Student#find_by_university_id(params[:univeristy_id])`. The `Student#where(university_id: params[:university_id])` will return an Array of students.

Comment: @JimStewart in which action do I put this code: `@student = Student.where(university_id: params[:university_id]).first` ?

Comment: Isn't there a way to have it interchangable i.e I can either use the `student_id` or the `university_id`?

Comment: Hey, if possible could we continue this in a chat room?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27517/discussion-between-teenomar-and-jim-stewart)